# need to random an array of images and words. Arc4random_uniform

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, arc4random

I'm working on a project of shapes and words. I currently have two arrays. One array is of images, the other array is just a set of strings that describes the first array of images. I'm using 4 buttons to display 4 items in the "string" array. Can someone please tell me how can I utilize arc4random but also make sure one of my 4 buttons display the name of the image.

Below is a quick example of my arrays

```
var myShapes = ["circle", "square", "rectangle"]

var images = ["circle.png", "square.png", "rectangle.png"]
```

How do I utilize arc4Random but make sure one item from each array always equals each other?

Adding information for the function to randomize my images.

```
func randomImage() -> UIImage {

    let arrayCount = UInt32(myImages.count)
    let unsignedRandomNumber = arc4random_uniform(arrayCount)
    let randomNumber = Int(unsignedRandomNumber)



    return UIImage(named: myImages[randomNumber])!

}
```

Below is how I'm doing the random text

```
    let randomDisplayText = buttonDisplayText[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(buttonDisplayText.count)))]
```

Comment: Can you use an associative array/dictionary? Or a 2d numeric array that holds both the data contain in `myShapes` and `images` for each entry?

Comment: `var images:[String] { return myShapes.map{$0 + ".png" }`

Comment: also-- telling us on how you plan on randomizing the array with `arc4random` would help. if you're just calculating a random key, you can reuse that key. @LeoDabus I think it's a fair assumption that the image paths won't always be their descriptions with `.png` appended?

Comment: Okay thank you for your comments. I believe I will have to follow the dictionary route to make this work. I'm trying to figure out how i use arc4random with a dictionary accessing a string and an UIImage. My code comes up with errors at the moment. Below is the function i wrote so far.

Comment: func randomImage() -> UIImage {    let index: Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(myImages.count)))
        let value = Array(myImages.values)[index]
        let key = Array(myImages.keys)[index]
        
        return (key, value!)

    }